# Storing a single Close price (NOT a series) in a variable - impossible?

Tags: pine-script, series, pine-script-v5

is it really impossible to store a single price in a variable without turning it into a series variable? It's freaking annoying. Please see below example code, the comments explain the problem. Thank you!

```
//@version=5
indicator("test")

// three random stocks
sec_1 = request.security("AAPL", "D", close)
sec_2 = request.security("MSFT", "D", close)
sec_3 = request.security("DOX", "D", close)

// supposed to fetch previous day's Close price of the above stocks
// a single value for each stock, not a series!

ar = array.new_float(3)

array.set(ar, 0, sec_1[1])
array.set(ar, 1, sec_2[1])
array.set(ar, 2, sec_3[1])

// sort by those single values. only makes sense with single values anyway?!
// but no error message

array.sort(ar)

// array supposed to contain single values, not series -> plot a line
// ... like this

plot(200, color=color.red)

// but plotting series. WHY???

plot(array.get(ar, 0))
plot(array.get(ar, 1))
plot(array.get(ar, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a series, always a series. As stated by the [user manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#series), using `close` in calculations in your case would yield a result of `series`.

> Built-in variables such as open, close, high, time or volume are of
> “series” form, as would be the result of expressions calculated using
> them.

If you want to have one single line, and not plot the historical values (series), you can use the `line.new()` function.

Comment: My code above is just an example, not a real use case.  
  
Turns out that any variable being used in a calculation will be converted into a series.  


`// this works `
`float v = 5`
`hline(v)`
  
`// this does not work`
`float v = 5`
`v := v +1`
`hline(v)`